# How do you escape strings when generating graphviz?

Tags: escaping, graphviz, dot

Any ideas how to escape arbitrary strings so that they're usable as labels in Graphviz `.dot` files?

I'm trying to dump a graph representation to `xdot` to aid with debugging some complicated transformation.

So I followed https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/escString/ to try to figure out how to escape quoted strings used as node and edge labels.

Basically, just escaping `\` and `"` to `\\` and `\"` respectively.

But escaping `\` seems to result in errors in `xdot` that actually point elsewhere.

```bash
$ (echo 'digraph { N[label="(\\s)"]; }') | xdot -
error: unknown xdot opcode ')'
```

Answer (score 1):

**dot** is happy with the escaped string, it seems to be an **xdot.py** bug.
dot produced:
[image]

Comment: Yeah.  That's what I expected to see.  Maybe I need to find an alternative to xdot.

Comment: A start: https://graphviz.org/resources/#graphical-interfaces  note particularly: https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz